# PHP + Facebook: how to get access_token + 60 day long access token?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, access-token, facebook-access-token

I am trying to get it this way:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?             
    client_id=APP_ID&
    client_secret=APP_SECRET&
    grant_type=fb_exchange_token&
    fb_exchange_token=EXISTING_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

All variable in the url address are set up properly, but when I put this url into the browser, I get:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "No user access token specified",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 1
   }
}
```

Over and over again. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

My current setup:
The address of the script: `www.domain.com/folder/index.php`

The `$my_url =  "www.domain.com"`

In Facebook: 
`namespace`: my_namespace

**app domains**: domain.com

**Site URL**: `http://www.domain.com/`

This is my setup, but still getting the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sending them the existing access token? You should first have an access_token, that you should send back to get the extended expiry access token.

From the error, what I can understand is, you are not sending them the token.

This is the code I answered in some other question.Its clearly given in the FB docs.This one gets the short lived token, sends it back to extend it, and gets the long lived access_token.

```
<?php

//read more : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/server-side-login/
session_start();
   $app_id = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
   $app_secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
   $my_url = "www.stackoverflow.com/";  // redirect url

    $code = $_REQUEST["code"];

   if(empty($code)) {
     // Redirect to Login Dialog
     $_SESSION['state'] = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE)); // CSRF protection
     $dialog_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
       . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url) . "&state="
       . $_SESSION['state'] . "&scope=publish_stream,read_friendlists,email";


     echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
   }
if($_SESSION['state'] && ($_SESSION['state'] === $_REQUEST['state'])) {
     $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
       . "client_id=" . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
       . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret . "&code=" . $code;

     $response = file_get_contents($token_url);
     $params = null;
     parse_str($response, $params);
     $longtoken=$params['access_token'];


//save it to database    
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Kishor for your answer. I've trie your code, but I have an issue with the `$my_url`. What this this URL in the facebook developer section? Let's say I have the app in `domain.com/my_addr/script_which_contains_the_code_above.php`, what should be in the `$my_url`? Thank you

Comment: It should be like, this script should be in the landing page where user comes in. So they are taken for oauth and you get an access token. They are redirected to your site where you want them to go to. That should be $my_url.

Comment: Kishor, please, take a look at the updated OP. Because I am a bit lost now, I added my current setup.

Comment: Still the same: `API Error Code: 191` - `API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application` - `Error Message: redirect_uri isn't an absolute URI. Check RFC 3986.`

Comment: I don't get it, but I created a new app, made a new setup and the script is working. So if I get it right - this script generated me the 60 day-long token. I will save this token and I can use it in my script for posting a status updates with CRON. After 60 days, this token will not working, I will need to request the new, then this new one again set up in the script for posting status updates and this over and over again?

Comment: New one will be the same token most probably, but with added expiry time. If the user goes to the Auth again between the 60 days, it is extended to 60 days expiry from the date.

Comment: It says explicitly somewhere in the docs, that a “new”/prolonged auth token _might_ be the same as the previous/existing one, but does not _have to be_. So I’d be careful relying on that being the case.

Comment: New one will be the same token `most probably` thats what I said mate. You seem to comment on a lot of answers I make by the way.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot put an App token there. It must be a *User* access token. Please use an existing *user* access token.